# Update table inserting VARBINARY data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

When I run the sql query I got something like this :

> Disallowed implicit conversion from data type varchar to data type
>   varbinary.... Use the CONVERT function to run this query. (severity
>   16)`

The data I want to insert looks like

```
'00001200000000000010000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF...FFF'
```

How to done this query?

Query looks like :

```
UPDATE <table> SET VARBINARY_DATA = '00001200000000000010000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF....' WHERE ID = 12
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From SQL Server 2005 onwards CONVERT does what you want:

```
CONVERT(varbinary(2000), '00001340132401324...', 2)
```

The styles for converting to/from binary are:

- 0: Raw data, ascii codepoints become binary bytes, UTF-16 codepoints become two bytes each.
- 1: Hex format, prefixed with '0x'
- 2: Hex format, not prefixed with '0x'

For converting characters to binary in format 0:

- `char` or `varchar` data (e.g. ASCII, ISO-8859-1) become binary bytes. For single character encodings this means one byte per character.
- `nchar` or `nvarchar` data (i.e. UTF-16) become two bytes each, in big-endian format, so `N'ABC'` becomes `0x410042004300`

For converting hex to binary in formats 1 and 2:

- Each two input hex digits become one byte
- If input is not valid hex an error occurs
- Whitespace and punctuation are not allowed

See MSDN:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

If you need UTF-8, please see my answer here for a UDF that will convert text to UTF-8:

- [Compute MD5 hash of a UTF8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200452/compute-md5-hash-of-a-utf8-string/35289890#35289890)