# Insert varbinary data into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table:

```
   (<NUM_TRF int
   ,<NAME, varchar(255),>
   ,<DESCRIPTION, text,>
   ,<REPORT, varbinary(max),>)
```

I try to create a script in SQL Server 2008, in order to insert a line on my local database,

```
INSERT INTO [MY_DB_APP].[dbo].[CONNECT_USER]
VALUES(1, 'name', 'description', Cast('wahid' As varbinary(max)) )
GO
```

but I get this error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021873/update-table-inserting-varbinary-data

Answer (score 38):

Two issues:

**Issue #1**: don't use `TEXT` anymore - it's deprecated. Use a `VARCHAR(n)` with a suitable size of `n`, or if you **really** must (only if you ***REALLY*** must), use `VARCHAR(MAX)`

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CONNECT_USER
(
    NUM_TRF int,
    NAME varchar(255),
    DESCRIPTION varchar(1000),
    REPORT varbinary(max)
)
```

I would personally also avoid writing EVERYTHING IN ALL CAPS - this just makes it so much harder to read! And I would try to avoid very *generic* column names like `Name` or `Description` - those are not very intuitive, and might collide with other table's columns and / or with SQL Server reserved keywords. Try to use **more expressive**, more context-related column names that make sense in your environment (`ConnectUsername` or whatever)

**Issue #2**: when doing an `INSERT`, I would recommend to **always** define the column you want to insert into. This avoids unpleasant surprises when a table is restructured or new columns are added:

```
INSERT INTO [MY_DB_APP].[dbo].[CONNECT_USER](NUM_TRF, NAME, DESCRIPTION, REPORT)
VALUES(1, 'name', 'description', CAST('wahid' AS VARBINARY(MAX)))
GO
```

Comment: If you guys are looking for something to clean a column which is varbinary, use:

update COLUMN set TABLE = cast('1' as varbinary(max)) where TABLE.CODE > 0

Comment: thanks a lot marc_s, it straight away converted my `text` to `varbinary`. It's very simple

Comment: I like the answer, but I would like to discuss and learn whether to use more expressive names for a already specific domain is really necessary. I mean, it's more concise and still clear enough if one can access name columns like `store.employee.name` and `store.client.name`, for instance, than repeating the tree naming all over, because we can also have different employee and client tables over multiple databases, and they could be called `store.store_client.store_client_name` and `enterprise.enterprise_client.enterprise_client_name`, for instance, following the same principle. Best regards.