# sql varbinary string to varbinary

Tags: sql-server

How I can convert or insert `'0x002D1ED54914534CAB1B2F2192A4620A01000000FB78B25328B7D36BA971BAE43E54F77C61ECDE8438B166C64D62406FECC2AFE4E788F36017B5F752'` intoa `varbinary` column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert varbinary data into SQL Server database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487445/insert-varbinary-data-into-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO {your table} VALUES (0x002D1ED54914534CAB1B2F2192A4620A01000000FB78B25328B7D36BA971BAE43E54F77C61ECDE8438B166C64D62406FECC2AFE4E788F36017B5F752)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try casting it:

```
SELECT CAST('0x002D1ED54914534CAB1B2F2192A4620A01000000FB78B25328B7D36BA971BAE43E54F77C61ECDE8438B166C64D62406FECC2AFE4E788F36017B5F752' AS VARBINARY)
```